# How can I find the missing index using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example

```
Order_ID Name
1        Man
2        Boss
5        Don
7        Lil
9        Dom
10       Bob
```

Want to get an output as:

```
3 4 6 8 are the missing Order_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `list` comprehension with `range`:

```
print([i for i in range(1, 10) if i not in df['Order_ID']])
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for generate missing values from index dynamically by maximum and minimum values:

```
print (np.setdiff1d(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1), df.index).tolist())
[3, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the list to set and compute its difference with a set that contains integers ranging from `min(lst)` and `max(lst)`.

```
lst=df["Order_ID"].to_list()
sorted(set(range(lst[0], lst[-1])) - set(lst))

> [3, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code;

**Code Syntax**

```
missData = list(filter(lambda x: x not in df['Order_ID'],  range(1, df['Order_ID].max()+1)))

print(f"{missData} are the missing Order_ID")
```

**Output**

```
[3, 4, 6, 8] are the missing Order_ID

[Program finished]
```